# Is there a way to do HDFS operations inside an executor in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I need to do some filesystem operations in parallel using pyspark. From the driver it is fairly easy to do it

```
Path = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
FileSystem = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem

# set OAuth conf using 
# spark.conf.set()

fs = Path('<abfss-path>').getFileSystem(sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())
data_outpout_stream = fs.create(Path('abfss-path>/<file-name>'), true, num_bytes)
```

I am scratching my head on how to do it from inside the executors. The executors do not have a spark context, and there is no way of passing one either. Neither can I copy over the spark config from the driver using a python dictionary and create a `Configuration` object inside the function `do_some_io`.

```
def do_some_io(i):
    fs = Path('<abfss-path>').getFileSystem(<some-magic-conf-here>)
    data_outpout_stream = fs.create(Path('<abfss-path>/<file-name>'), true, num_bytes)

rdd = sc.parallelize(range(0, 100))
rdd.foreach(lambda i : do_some_io(i))
```

Tried setting `spark.executor.allowSparkContext` to `true` and restarted the cluster, no luck

Comment: You could try using other libraries like pyarrow or pyhdfs or snakebite inside the executors

Comment: ...or distribute hadoop configs to the executors first, with `spark.files` and setting  `spark.executorEnv.HADOOP_CONF_DIR=` and then use your `do_some_io` function.